# How can I return an interface to an EJB through SOAP?

Tags: java, ejb, factory

I want to build a factory class which:

- instantiates a new instance of an EJB on a server
- returns the remote interface to that bean to the client
- via SOAP

Practically, what I'm trying to do is create a set of games on a server, instances of a class Game let's say, via a remote method invocation -- each time I call that method ("newGameOnServer()", maybe), I want to get back (on the client) a reference to that particular game's remote interface.

Is this possible?  Can someone point me to some example code?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean remote interface as in an @Remote interface that uses RMI, you can't do that via SOAP.

But... you could have the SOAP service return the info needed for the client to **create** an `javax.naming.InitialContext` and **lookup** the remote interface.  That could be kind of neat.  A nice little SOAP registry service.